# jQuery Rotate prevent stacking function after a click

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-rotation

[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/wxBM2/8/)

Hello,
I am using this [jQueryRotate plugin](https://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/) to rotate my div's after a user clicks on the button.

I would like to stop stacking the rotation after the button is clicked more than once. It just keeps on speeding up.

I have researched it and using `.stop()` nor `return false;` wont help.
All I want is to know, whether there is a way to reset the rotation on the next click, or stop it after clicking on another button.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just a quick note, I found its a bug, the rotation speed is not increasing. If I change tabs and return back to the jsfiddle the speed has returned to normal. It is some sort of rendering glitch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The glitch came from having the declaration multiple times in the loop.
I pulled the variables outside the click event which stopped the glitch.

To prevent the speed increasing, i did a quick check to see if the button had already been clicked. See below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var angle = 0
    var angleone = 0;
    var clicked = false;
    $('.concept').click(function () {
        if (!clicked) {
            setInterval(function () {
                angle += 3;
                $(".gear").rotate(angle);
            }, 50);

            setInterval(function () {
                angleone -= 3;
                $(".gear-one").rotate(angle);
            }, 50);
            clicked = true;
        }
    });
    $('.bar').click(function () {
        if ($('#default').is(':visible')) {
            $('#default').fadeOut(200);
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly what I wanted to do, just didn't really know how! :) Anyway, you made my day! :) A quick note, why does the grey square not rotate counter-clockwise, since it has -= 3 degrees iterator?

Comment: I just realised it is because for gear-one the code is using angle not angleone on the rotate function.

Comment: It doesnt change anything... Can you please provide jsfiddle?